# Assign a Special String Value(Iphone Development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to assign the Bellow characters(same as Shown below)to Nsstring.How can i do that??

It gives error when i assign these values.

```
,"from":{"name"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `"` as they are used to denote start-end of string.

```
NSString *srt = @",\"from\":{\"name\"";
```